# Xcode UIView.init(frame:) must be used from main thread only

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, uikit

I'm trying to render some views in background thread to not affect the main thread. That was never a problem before Xcode 9.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let customView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.view.addSubview(customView)
    }
}
```

> UIView.init(frame:) must be used from main thread only

This error occurs in the second line.

**Update**

The Apple `UIView` Documentation actually says in the *Threading Considerations* section:

> Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the main thread. Thus, you should always call the methods of the UIView class from code running in the main thread of your application. **The only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view object itself, but all other manipulations should occur on the main thread.**

Comment: I was aware of this new rule, but I wonder how much of the work you can still offload to a backgroudn thread...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Xcode 9 has a new runtime **[Main Thread Checker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker)** that detects call to UIKit from a background thread and generate warnings.

I know its meant to generate warnings and not crash the app, but you can try disabling Main Thread Checker for your test target.

[image]

I tried this code in a sample project, the debugger paused at the issue (as it is supposed to), but the app didn't crash.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let v = UIView(frame: .zero)
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it for now. Thanks!

Comment: In my case i was calling a method from within URLSession request.

Answer (score 33):

#### Main Thread Entry

You can enter the main thread as follows

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    // UIView usage
}
```

Comment: From Review:  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 24):

You can use this function

```
func downloadImage(urlstr: String, imageView: UIImageView) {
    let url = URL(string: urlstr)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // Make sure you're on the main thread here
            imageview.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

How to use this function?

```
downloadImage(urlstr: "imageUrl", imageView: self.myImageView)
```

Answer (score 2):

For Objective C:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // UIView usage
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    });
```